# Robotics Experts: How to do trajectory planning for a robotic arm

Tags: control, robotics, motion

I have a homemade 3D printed prosthetic robotic arm similar to the picture below

[image]

Right now this is completely open loop control system. The elbow, wrist and base can only rotate in around its primary axis. I enter the angle that the base, elbow and wrist should rotate and it performs that action - nothing else happens. Each of the finger is actuated by a motor and that enables grip and release of each fingers and this is controlled by an entirely different control system at a much lower output voltage than the wrist, elbow and base motors.

But I do not feel that very sophisticated. I wish modify this arm so to make it more "industry" purpose.

What should I do to get started in developing a control algorithm for the trajectory of this arm?

Some thoughts: maybe add some "sensors" that provides angle information of the arm in space? Can someone who is familiar with robotics provide me with some information as to how this is done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One "quick" solution (not necessarily that quick, but quicker and more robust than starting from scratch) is to use something like [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) to generate position information for a configuration you want your robot to take; Basically your input is
two or more states the are should be in, and blender can compute the necessary angles and interpolations between the two. Since Blender is scriptable using Python, you might even be able to drive the robotic arm "real-time" from inside Blender: [obligatory Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwZkB1PXyvU).

If your interested in how to write code which could do the solving part for you, the key algorithm to understand is [inverse kinematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_kinematics). This is all about finding the joint parameters given a desired position/orientation. It is not something which is easy to solve (it requires solving non-linear systems of equations), but is certainly do-able.

Close-loop feedback is not necessarily required, however you do need to be able to accurately position limbs. One open loop solution is to use stepper motors and a known "home" position. The software can track what it thinks the current orientation of the arm is by simply tracking what operations it did moving away from the home position.